# Why my script.js file doesn't work but the JavaScript code inside of the index.html file works?

Tags: javascript

When i add this:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

to my index.html file in the head of the file, and i create a JavaScript file, it looks like the html doesn't recognize it.

But when i add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //code
</script>
```

to my index.html file in the body of the file, all of the code i done in JavaScript works.

Can somebody explain why this happens?

Comment: add your external js files at the bottom of the body instead of the head

Comment: `script.js` needs to come after jquery.

Answer (score 1):

It’s always a good practice to add jQuery code just before the closing `</body>` tag. If you have not done that, then use the `defer` attribute.

Also if you’re writing jQuery code make sure that your code is placed after the jQuery link code.

Answer (score 1):

Don't add your JS files in the head. You are most likely going to be accessing DOM elements, and those elements are defined in the HTML. If you insert a script above the html, the elements won't be recognized because they're not defined yet. Add all of your scripts after the body, I add mine after the closing html just to be safe. And please add your script after your jQuery script.